# Align the text in pdf correctly using fpdf

Tags: php, fpdf

I have to create a `pdf file`. I am using **fpdf**.
My pdf file should look like this:

```
This is a sample pdf.
Hello world.
sample text sample text.
```

But these lines are displayed in undesired manner.

My code is

```
require('fpdf.php');

$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm','A4');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'This is a sample pdf.');
$pdf->Cell(0,30,'Hello world.');
$pdf->Cell(0,50,'sample text sample text.');
$pdf->Output();
```

the resulted pdf is looked like this:

[image]

How can I align the text in pdf correctly?

Comment: what aligment? columns or rows? for `Cell` specify the correct width so it will not extend to the right
Refer to documentation http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [FPDF documentation](http://www.fpdf.org/) about [Cell()](http://www.fpdf.org/en/doc/cell.htm) function:

```
Cell(float w [, float h [, string txt [, mixed border [, int ln [, string align [, boolean fill [, mixed link]]]]]]])
```

> After the call, the current position moves to the right or to the next line.
>
> **ln**
>       Indicates where the current position should go after the call. Possible values are:
>
> ```
>     0: to the right
>     1: to the beginning of the next line
>     2: below
> ```
>
> Putting 1 is equivalent to putting 0 and calling Ln() just after. Default value: 0.

Try this:

```
$pdf->Cell(0,10,'This is a sample pdf.', 0, 1);
                                         ^ no border
                                            ^ after the call move to beginning of next line
```

Comment: I had that kind of issue with "current position" a lot with FPDF. In general I find its doc very clear and once you understood how it works, a few tries is enough to get where is the current position. :)